# Authenticating any request with azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, spring-saml

I am working with an application which uses Azure AD for authentication.
It is a spring web application uses Spring SAML to send/manage authentication request/response with Azure AD.
Right now the application is configured to use Azure AD auth during application login, so that Azure will reply to the configured reply URL and i will take up the response from there.

Now, I want to use Azure AD for authenticating that my web app receives.
Problem with Azure AD is reply URL has to be configured.
Say i receive a random request, how can i use SAML to send a auth request to Azure AD and if auth is success then i have to redirect to the random request.

I explore some things like relay state, redirect url(seems like azure AD is not supporting).

Please let me know if there are any other approach that could help me.

Thanks,
Sivaprakash

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "random request" ? different parameter  in request ?

Comment: E.g:When a user log in, I make a request to /saml/sso which is mapped to SamlEntryPoint, which opens a saml request to Azure AD. Upon a successful response, SAML redirects to a default target URL which is home page of my app.

My application is stateless and operates with JWT token, so any page with a token could be requested. Say there is a page to view reports. /reports. i need to authenticate this request with Azure AD and after the login it should redirect to /reports and not to the home page.